# How should Z value be compared with depth value?

Tags: opengl

I'd like to know whether a different model is drawn just before coordinate (xyz) where it's here.
It doesn't work by Z value comparison of depth value and the coordinate I did world change of.

It seems that Z value is normalized in near=0, far=1, but depth value seems to make the point of view drawn at the most inside in View frustum 1.

## When I moved a far plane to a far place, Z value decreased, but depth value didn't change.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but I will make a guess and provide an answer. Apologies in advance if this is not what you were asking. In OpenGL you need to understand what the view frustum is. In it, you have an x and y coordinate and a depth value. The depth value represents how far from your eye the object (pixel) drawn is. This is so that you can avoid having objects i the background obfuscate objects that are closer in, giving a more real representation of the reality. You also have clipping planes, a near and a far clipping planes. Anything closer than the nera clipping plane will not be drawn, and anything farther than the far clipping plane won't be drawn. If, for example, I am drawing an image of the earth from space. I know I won't have to bother with anything that is on the other side of the Earth and can just clip it away, speeding things up. Usually, the near clipping plane is set at z=0, and the far clipping plane at depth=1. Then, this interval is subdivided (depending on your depth buffer) and OpenGL, as said, will put each pixel in each slot and decide what is closer to your eye and what is not (on the same line drawn from the eye to the pixel x,y). If you are in 3D and have x,y,z, the z-value from the scene won't match the value of the depth value, you need to use the view-matrix to map things right.

Hopefully this helps some.